# How to create a video background for my app in Kotlin? setVideoURI and setVideoPath are not working

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile-development

I know this has been asked numerous of times, but apparently all guides are for Java.

I need to create a video background for my app in Kotlin.

I created a VideoView in the XML and gave it the id: bgVideoView.

On the main activity, right below the setContentView(...) line, I wrote the following two lines (I copied the path from the video itself, it didn't worked, so I made a URI (See after the two lines)):

```
bgVideoView.setVideoPath("src/main/res/raw/emiratesbackground.mp4");
bgVideoView.start();
```

On the phone however, I am getting the error: Sorry, this video cannot be played.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Many thanks!

It's worth mentioning that other questions cover the topic for Java. But something in the syntax of Kotlin, makes things difficult for me. For instance the following line of code is apparently invalid in Kotlin.

```
private MediaPlayer mp = null;
```

Followed the tips provided I wrote the following code, but I still can't play the video:

```
val videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://org.android.com.example.flightmobileapp/raw/emiratesbackground");
And overall, my code looks like that:

package com.example.flightmobileapp

import android.net.Uri
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log.e
import android.widget.VideoView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://org.android.com.example.flightmobileapp/raw/emiratesbackground");

        bgVideoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
        bgVideoView.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem. to play a video use the following code:

```
val videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + R.raw.emirates );
        bgVideoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
        bgVideoView.start();
        bgVideoView.setOnCompletionListener {
            bgVideoView.start();
        }
```